# Statsmodels ARIMA: how to get 0, 10, 20, .., 90,100 percentile forecast?

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting, arima, percentile

My goal is compute various percentile forecast for the same day.

My code:

```
# import the data
catfish_sales = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/time-series-toy-data-set/catfish.csv',
                           parse_dates = [0], index_col=0, date_parser=parse_date)
train_data, test_data = np.split(catfish_sales, 
                                 [int(len(catfish_sales)*0.95)])
forecast_data = pd.DataFrame()
for conf in range(0,101,10):
    # Perform arima fit and forecast
    aux_df = arima.fit().get_forecast(steps=len(test_data)).conf_int(alpha=(1-(conf/100)))
    #     print(forecast_data.dtypes)
    aux_df['Total_forecast'] = aux_df[['lower Total', 'upper Total']].mean(axis=1)
    conf_lbl = 'p'+str(conf)+'_'
    aux_df = aux_df.add_prefix(conf_lbl)
    print(aux_df.head())
    forecast_Data = pd.concat([forecast_data,aux_df],axis=0)
```

Present output:

```
            p0_lower Total  p0_upper Total  p0_Total_forecast
2011-08-01    15273.493541    15273.493541       15273.493541
2011-09-01    14611.272886    14611.272886       14611.272886
2011-10-01    13929.948620    13929.948620       13929.948620
2011-11-01    11729.123604    11729.123604       11729.123604
2011-12-01    12358.778644    12358.778644       12358.778644
            p10_lower Total  p10_upper Total  p10_Total_forecast
2011-08-01     15130.404131     15416.582950        15273.493541
2011-09-01     14442.952828     14779.592943        14611.272886
2011-10-01     13747.205922     14112.691318        13929.948620
2011-11-01     11535.026991     11923.220217        11729.123604
2011-12-01     12154.903296     12562.653992        12358.778644

.....................

p90_lower Total  p90_upper Total  p90_Total_forecast
2011-08-01     13400.513982     17146.473099        15273.493541
2011-09-01     12408.034870     16814.510902        14611.272886
2011-10-01     11537.924366     16321.972875        13929.948620
2011-11-01      9188.481426     14269.765781        11729.123604
2011-12-01      9690.136982     15027.420306        12358.778644
            p100_lower Total  p100_upper Total  p100_Total_forecast
2011-08-01              -inf               inf                  NaN
2011-09-01              -inf               inf                  NaN
2011-10-01              -inf               inf                  NaN
2011-11-01              -inf               inf                  NaN
2011-12-01              -inf               inf                  NaN
```

My question:

1. Is confidence level and percentile both same? In the above, I assumed both as same. I considered 90% confidence as 90 percentile forecast, etc.
2. I just need one value for each confidence or percentile. In the above, I just computed mean of upper and lower boundary. But I noticed an interesting thing: mean values at all the percentile or confidence level are same. This could mean my assumption of confidence interval and percentile seems to be wrong. I appreciate your help.
3. I need to compute various percentile forecast for same day as I am trying above. I appreciate if you could suggest me a model that I can compute these if ARIMA is not the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

After referring the following document: [http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/eps_120/Toolkits/Toolkit_04.pdf](http://seismo.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirchner/eps_120/Toolkits/Toolkit_04.pdf)

This is what I understood and conclude:
[image]